# R Boruta - merging dataframe with confirmed features by column name

Tags: r, algorithm, dataframe, feature-selection, data-wrangling

I have run a Boruta algorithm on a large dataset (> 500 covariates), and have got a dataframe of confirmed or rejected features using , which looks like this. Each observation being a feature from my original dataset `(pred_recent_pf_bin)`.

```
boruta_pf_recent <- Boruta(pred_recent_pf_bin ~ . , data = pf_recent_use, doTrace = 2)
pf_recent_boruta_df <- attStats(boruta_pf_recent)
str(pf_recent_boruta_df)
'data.frame':   517 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ meanImp  : num  11.0438 0.0399 -0.3744 4.6134 -0.2527 ...
 $ medianImp: num  11.0482 0.0624 -0.6632 4.4585 -0.628 ...
 $ minImp   : num  8.62 -2.13 -1.24 3.34 -1.74 ...
 $ maxImp   : num  13.69 1.85 1.07 6.52 1.67 ...
 $ normHits : num  1 0 0 0.98 0 ...
 $ decision : Factor w/ 3 levels "Tentative","Confirmed",..: 2 3 3 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...
```

I have subsetted the dataframe to contain just the confirmed features:

`boruta_confirmed <- subset(pf_recent_boruta_df, subset = pf_recent_boruta_df$decision == "Confirmed")`

Then transposed it and cleared the algorithm stats

`conf <- t(boruta_confirmed) conf_empty <- conf[-c(1:6), ]`

So now I've got a dataframe with no observations and the column headers from my original dataset `(pred_recent_pf_bin)`. I would like to merge the observations from my original dataset to the column headers in `conf_empty`. I have tried a variety of merge() combinations, but cannot figure out which way it should be configured

```
str(conf_empty)
 chr[0 , 1:468] 
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr [1:468] "houseID" "Bangsa" "farmWork" "BilaMasaSelalunyaKamuPergiTidur" ...
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out - in case its useful for anyone else!

```
#subset to for confirmed and rejected variables 
boruta_confirmed <- subset(pf_recent_boruta_df, subset = pf_recent_boruta_df$decision == "Confirmed")
boruta_rejected <- subset(pf_recent_boruta_df, subset = pf_recent_boruta_df$decision == "Rejected")

#make empty dataframe of rejected column variable names
str(boruta_rejected)
rej <- t(boruta_rejected)
rej_empty <- rej[-c(1:6), ]

# get names of rejected columns
rej_names <- colnames(rej_empty[,2:49])
cols_rej <- c(rej_names)

#remove rejected columns from original dataframe
pf_recent_confirmed <- pf_recent[, !(colnames(pf_recent) %in% cols_rej)]
```